# Inset on basic UITableViewCell textLabel changes between devices

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` with a "Settings" title label, and below it a tableview with some basic `UITableviewCell`s.

On my iPhone 11 the tableview sets the inset on the cells to 20px, but when I change to a smaller device (iPhone 8) you can see that the indentation on the tableview is now less than 20px.

I either want to:

1. identify the indent used, and match it on my title
2. set the indent on the tableview to 20px

I can fix all of this by making the Settings label a header for the tableview, but i don't really want to do that right now.

[image: iPhone 8]
[image: iPhone 11]

[image: The VC layout]